# MySQL: Updating a column referenced by two foreign keys in the same table leads to foreign key constraint failure

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.5

I have a simple InnoDB table:

```
CREATE TABLE `T` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `other` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And another table that encodes relationships among entries from the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `T_T` (
  `id1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deleted1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deleted2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id1`,`deleted1`,`id2`,`deleted2`),
  KEY `fk_T_T_2_idx` (`id2`,`deleted2`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_T_T_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id2`, `deleted2`) REFERENCES `T` (`id`, `deleted`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_T_T_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id1`, `deleted1`) REFERENCES `T` (`id`, `deleted`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Creation of tables and population works perfectly fine.

```
INSERT INTO T (id, deleted, other) VALUES (1, 0, 'whatever');
INSERT INTO T_T (id1, deleted1, id2, deleted2) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 0);
```

Updating an entry in T, however,  with something like this:

```
UPDATE T SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

leads to the following error:

```
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`test`.`T_T`, CONSTRAINT `fk_T_T_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id1`, `deleted1`) REFERENCES `T` (`id`, `deleted`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

As noted by others, this works if the entries in T_T don't refer to self (id1 != id2).  But an UPDATE will fail when a row in T_T refers with both ids to the same row in T.

Is there a problem in MySQL with foreign keys that refer to another table's column(s) twice?
Is there a work around for something like this?

Comment: [SQLFiddle works fine](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23980/1)

Comment: @Alexander You don't have any records in `T_T` that reference the foreign key that you modify.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that demonstrates it working fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1574c9/1

Comment: This one shows that the update cascaded properly: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1574c9/2

Comment: also works on my 5.0.77 version

Comment: It won't work if you insert a record into T_T that refers to self: INSERT INTO T_T(id1, deleted1, id2, deleted2) VALUES
(1, 2141, 1, 1432);  An update of this record in T fails.  That's exactly what I am running into in my production system.

Comment: GregS I did. From Barmar 's fiddle

Comment: @GregS If I try to do that, the `UPDATE` will try to create a duplicate primary key in table `T`.

Comment: @Barmer I don't see how that happens. The insertions into both T and T_T work. For example, let T have (1,2) and T_T (1,2,1,2). No duplicate records there. The update would make T contain (1,3) and that should cascade into T_T to contain (1,3,1,3). T_T's primary key is over all 4 columns. Where is duplicate key in either T or T_T?

Comment: @Barmer It almost appears that the foreign keys in T_T are updated separately. The sequence of internal MySQL operations appears to be: 1) update the record in T; b) cascade to the first foreign key in T_T; c) cascade to the second foreign key in T_T.  But after step b) the second's foreign key constraints fail because it now points to a  non-existent row in T.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @GregS you are right, this is a known limitation of MySQL's implementation of foreign key - or to be precise of how the `UPDATE` and constraints check interact.

Comment: @ypercube This is the correct answer.  If you form it as an answer I will gladly accept it.